# ERROR : .lenth property is not defined?

Tags: javascript

```
var model = 
{
numShips:3,
boardSize:7, 
shipLength:3,
shipSunk:0,

ships:[

{
    locations: ["10","20","30"],
    hits : ["hit","","hit"]
},

{
    locations:["20","21","22"],
    hits:["hit","",""]
},

{
    locations:["33","34","35"],
    hits:["hit","hit","hit"]
}

],

fire:function(guess)
{

   for(var i=0;i<model.ships.length;i++)
   {
       for(var j=0;j<model.ships.locations.length;j++)
       {
           if(guess==(model.ships[i].locations[j]))
           {
               model.ships[i].hits[j]="hit";
               console.log(model.ships[i].hits[j]);              

           }
       }
   }

}
};

  model.fire(21);
```

I just want to check that if the value i'm passing through guess is equal to any value of locations array and then if it has then i would just update its corresponding hits array and mark that location as hit. But this is giving me error like .length property is not defined. Can u help me out?

Comment: ships is an array. You will have to loop over it

Comment: In your second for loop you're not targeting `model.ships[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In second for-loop you want to iterate locations of ship from the first for-loop. You need to access it by index:

```
for(var j=0;j<model.ships[i].locations.length;j++) ...
// -----------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have already commented, `ships` is an array and you will have to loop over it and check `currentIteration.location.length`

You do not need to use loop on `locations` to match. You can use `array.indexOf()` to get index and use `item.hits[index]`

You can try something like this:

```js
var model = {
  numShips: 3,
  boardSize: 7,
  shipLength: 3,
  shipSunk: 0,

  ships: [{
    locations: ["10", "20", "30"],
    hits: ["hit", "", "hit"]
  }, {
    locations: ["20", "21", "22"],
    hits: ["hit", "test", ""]
  }, {
    locations: ["33", "34", "35"],
    hits: ["hit", "hit", "hit"]
  }],

  fire: function(guess) {
    model.ships.forEach(function(item) {
      var _index = item.locations.indexOf(guess.toString());
      if(_index>=0){
        console.log(item.hits[_index])
      }
    })
  }
};

model.fire(21);
```

Comment: @sony I have updated my answer. I have also removed loop over `locations`